# Making Python code snippets available to internal non-technical userbase?

Tags: python, sql, flask

This is a more general question pertaining to a business need.

At my company many requests come through that require an analyst to run a mini "code snippets". These code snippets could be in SQL, Python, R, or a combination of the languages.

The code is often extremely simple (<30 lines) and either doesn't change or changes minimally from request to request (i.e. the "where" statement of a SQL query might change).

I am wondering what the best way is to give a "non-tech" interface to the users where they can run these code snippets while maintaining version control on my side?

Potential problems I've thought of:

1. I want to ensure that the users don't have direct access to the code as they could easily break it.
2. Additionally, if there was some way to version control the software that would be ideal as well. I'd rather that an update to Pandas (Python) or any other software/module not break all the scripts. I don't know how this is possible.
3. The users have no tech background so running code from the command line, anaconda prompt, git bash or any other cmd like interface is probably not an option.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Do the users have to run these scripts on their own machines? It seems like based on your tags you might have an idea of where to go. Make a Flask API that runs the code snippets when called.

Comment: Also, you should know that questions such as these are difficult for us to answer, and it'll probably be closed as a result. Stack Overflow tends to prefer questions that have definitive, usually code driven answers.

Comment: I think this is more of an opinion-based question. Anyway, I had used [__gitlab__](https://about.gitlab.com/) hosted on my own ubuntu server in the past, it might be worth to check it out! Also check out [__gogs__](https://gogs.io/)

Comment: @Ares The users do not have to run the scripts on their own machines. Would I host the Flask API on some kind of internal server? I can't host over the web as sensitive data might be called/transferred.

Additionally, is there a different stack website where this kind of discussion is more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) and/or [Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/). You can save annotated code snippets to a central server as notebooks that can be edited and run in the browser (including output from Pandas dataframes and matplotlib/seaborn graph plotting) by users as needs demand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I work with Jupyter often while I'm doing iterative data analysis/data exploration. My concern is giving a platform to the users where they have access to the code (users have 0 programming experience, so even seeing code will cause panic/there is potential they will accidentally delete something and cause the program to break). Can I provide Jupyter notebooks and maintain version control on my end somehow?

Comment: I see your concern, I'm not sure about any sort of rx-only notebooks.